# How to print multiple int in java

Tags: java, printing

how to print multiple int in java using System.out.println?

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;

System.out.println("%d%d%d",a,b,c); // error occurs
```

Comment: using % than + " " +

Comment: You need `printf` instead of `println` if you use the `%d` format.

Comment: @Kayaman is that kind of the same format in C?

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) for more info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you meant to use `printf()`, not `println()`:

```java
System.out.printf("%d%d%d%n", a, b, c);
```

(`%n` prints a platform-specific line-separator, to stay consistent with the original output.)

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using `System.out.println()` instead of the better matching `System.out.printf()`, as suggested in [Mureinik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60764972/1554195), it should look like this:

```
System.out.println( String.format( "%d%d%d", a, b, c ) );
```